# How to convert date as string to date type

Tags: python, datetime

I have a variable `'2019-05-30 21:01:09'` that needs to be converted into `2019-05-30 21:01:09`. What is the best way to go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can using datetime library

```py
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime('2019-05-30 21:01:09', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime

strToDate = datetime.strptime('2019-05-30 21:01:09','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

strptime() allows for the conversion of string to date time object provided that you give the format the function should expect as the second argument